# Paging3 keeps loading data even when there is no user interaction when recyclerview is inside nested scroll view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-paging-3

I have been trying to make recycler view work with scroll view instead of nested scroll view but all in vain my use case is that I need to make the recycler view scroll with the complete layout the use case achieved easily with nested scroll view but it keeps calling the API because nested scroll view needs to know how many children it needs to accommodate. If there is any other workaround or anything that can make paging work with scroll or nested scroll view

here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="comapp.viewmodels.HomeViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
                app:count="@{viewModel.cartCount}" />
            <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:indicatorColor="@color/app_global_green"
                android:indeterminate="true" />

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/searchcard"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                        android:elevation="15dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <SearchView
                            android:id="@+id/search_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_search_view"
                            android:elevation="15dp"
                            android:queryHint="Search by Product ID or name" />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/start_your_business"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="Apna karobar shuru karein \n asaani say"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/start_your_"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchcard" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_watch_video"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/start_your_business"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/green_dark"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                        app:cardElevation="15dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start_your_business">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/watch_video"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/bg_home_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/btn_watch_video"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_backhome"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_watch_video" />

                    <!--
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/top_categories"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/top_categories"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/home_headings"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bg_home_image" />-->
                    <!--

                           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                               android:id="@+id/category_home_grid"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:clipToPadding="true"
                               android:orientation="horizontal"
                               app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_categories"
                               app:listTopCategories="@{viewModel.topCategories}"
                               app:spanCount="2"
                               tools:itemCount="16"
                               tools:listitem="@layout/category_grid_view_home"/>
                           <ImageView
                               android:id="@+id/status_image"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                               app:markazApiStatus="@{viewModel.status}" />-->


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/home_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/btn_watch_video"
                        android:src="@drawable/home_image"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg_home_image"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg_home_image"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/sort"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_catalogs">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                            android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:entries="@array/filterTypes"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/top_catalogs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/bg_home_image"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/top_catalogs"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/home_headings"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/home_image"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.068"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/home_image"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bg_home_image" />

              <!--      <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/shimmer"
                        android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sort"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_catalog" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>-->

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/catalog_home_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/top_catalogs"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"

                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sort"
                        app:spanCount="1"
                        tools:itemCount="8"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/viewholder_catalog" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/status_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/top_catalogs"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catalog_home_list" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/cvResellerInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/home_image">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/share_product_and_place_order"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This could be a bit complicated, the recyclerView on its own manages the ho data is being displayed and manipulated. check the answer from here if it solves your problem.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910710/how-can-we-scroll-parent-layout-while-scrolling-recyclerview-android)